# CSS 3d correctly sort cube drawing order

Tags: html, css, sorting, css-transforms

So I've been messing around with css, but I've run into a sort of a problem. Here is my code:

```css
.cube {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.scene {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.back {
  background-color: #ee5500;
  transform: translateZ(-30px);
}

.right {
  background-color: #ff8800;
  transform: translateX(30px) rotateY(90deg);
}

.top {
  background-color: #ffaa00;
  transform: translateY(-30px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.c1 {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(45deg) translateY(0px);
}

.c2 {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(45deg) translateY(60px) translateZ(0) translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube c2">
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side top"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cube c1">
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side top"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/qwertyquerty/pen/NyBZNd

So what I am trying to accomplish is getting c2 to appear behind c1 as if its top was connected to the bottom of the c1. For some reason c2 is displaying in front of c1, which is not what I want. I can't seem to fix this, I've tried many things including z-index. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I don't know the reason, but the problem arises from the transform-style on scene:

```css
.cube {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.scene {
  /*transform-style: preserve-3d; */
}

.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.back {
  background-color: #ee5500;
  transform: translateZ(-30px);
}

.right {
  background-color: #ff8800;
  transform: translateX(30px) rotateY(90deg);
}

.top {
  background-color: #ffaa00;
  transform: translateY(-30px) rotateX(90deg);
}

.c1 {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(45deg) translateY(0px);
}

.c2 {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateY(45deg) translateY(60px) translateZ(0) translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube c2">
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side top"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cube c1">
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side top"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```